# After Jquery upgrade using minification the site is breaking in AEM

Tags: jquery, aem

We are using AEM 6.1, jQuery 1.12.4 version. There is a requirement to upgrade jQuery to 3.5 + and followed https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/ .

So when tried upgrading to jquery-3.6.0.min.js version without minification in Adobe Granite HTML library  the site is working fine. But when minification is turned on the site is breaking and i found out the error we are getting in jQuery minification file i.e.,

[image]

Any clue on how to solve this minification problem

Regards,

Sree.

Comment: First of all: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without more information (more logs, AEM version), but in my experience is because the deprecated YUI is not able to minify the JS. Try to use GCC instead or identify the line that is breaking the minification. Using YUI separately can give you the line number. See as reference https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/07/10/how-to-use-the-google-closure-compiler-with-aem6-2/